# How to properly use the self validation expressions #??

Tags: enums, karate

So I have a response with the field role is of type enum

```
'{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "roles": [],
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "roles": [
                "manager"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "roles": [
                "client"
            ],
        }
    ],
}'
```

I want to validate that the role in response is of type enum so I was trying  something like

```
* match each response..role == ['#? enumRoles.contains(_)'}
```

But kept getting errors. The solution I was trying is dervied from
[How to validate multiple possible values in Karate using a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307140/how-to-validate-multiple-possible-values-in-karate-using-a-schema). Then I found out that the accepted solution there was also yielding unexpected end of file and message not supported errors.

Any help is appreciated. I am using 1.2.0.RC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more trickier than I expected, but here is a solution. Please read the docs to understand what the API does.

```
* def response =
"""
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "roles": [],
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "roles": [
                "manager"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "roles": [
                "client"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
"""
* def roles = ['manager', 'client']
* def temp1 = $..roles[*]
* def temp2 = karate.distinct(temp1)
* match roles contains temp2
```

There is no such thing as enum in plain JSON. Consider writing custom JS functions if needed, here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567412/143475

Comment: Works perfectly. Very clever solution.